# Как сравнить каждый символ строки с каждым

Tags: javascript, строки, скрипт

Есть строка, и надо написать алгоритм,который проверяет,есть ли в строке два одинаковых символа.

```
var stt = 'ABC';
    var i;
    var a;
   for(i = 0; i<stt.length;i++) {
       for(a = 1; a<stt.length; a++) {
         if(stt.charAt(i) == stt.charAt(a)) {
             console.log('true');
         }
       }

   }
```

Но дело в том,что сравниваются два одних и тех же элемента и фактически,это выглядит так

```
if(stt.charAt(1) == stt.charAt(1)) {
    console.log('true'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const foo = str => /(.).*\1/.test(str); 

// проверка
['ABC', 'AABC', 'ABbC', 'ABCAD'].forEach(s => console.log(`'${s}': ${foo(s)}`));
```

Еще простой вариант:

```
const bar = str => str.length !== (new Set(str)).size;
```

---

Алгоритм (не тех выражений которые выше!), естесственно на JS, для краткости:

```
function baz(str) {
  const len = str.length; 
  for (let c, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c = str.charAt(i); 
    for (let j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (str.charAt(j) === c)
        return true; 
    }
  }
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: с регуляркой норм вариант)), только боюсь за алгоритм не прокатит))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да, ведь они созданы как раз для таких задач :) Кстати, не удивлюсь если регулярка окажется еще и быстрее прочих подходов... выражение достаточно простое. А насчет алгоритма, дополню ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так сделал:

```js
// разбиваем строку на символы и применяем свертку
let counts = 'ABBCA'.split("").reduce((a, c) => {
  // считаем символы в аккумуляторе
  return (a[c] = ++a[c] || 1) && a;
},{});

// ищем в результате свертки счетчик со значением больше 1 
let result = Object.values(counts).filter(i => i != 1).length > 0;

console.log(counts)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stt = 'asfafgadgjkasjfkladfkgjdflkgjkldfgj';
var temp = stt; // переносим во временную переменную
var exist = false; // выставляем флаг который будет определять есть ли в строке одинаковые символы
for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){ // тут все ясно должно быть идем по строке
    for(j = i+1; j < temp.length; j++){ // проходим все символы от текущего до конца строки для поиска одинаковых символов
        if(temp[i] == temp[j]){ // само сравнение
            exist = true; // если символы одинаковые переводим флаг в true
            temp = temp.split(temp[i]).join(''); // удаляем все одинаковые символы из временной строки(не обьязательно)
        }
    }
}
console.log(exist);
```

Для оптимизации можно во второй цыкл break закинуть)